# When are Infinitesimal $\mathfrak{g}-$actions Lie homomorphisms?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

A short background from *Smooth Manifolds, by Lee*.

Given $G$ a Lie group and a **right** $G$-action on a smooth manifold $M$, we have an infinitesimal $\mathfrak{g}:=Lie(G)$-action over $M$. That is, a Lie homomorphism $\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(M)$, where $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is the Lie algebra of vector fields over $M$ with the natural bracket. Moreover, if we are considering a **left** $G$-action, we can still define an infinitesimal $\mathfrak{g}$-action in the same way, however the induced map $\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is a Lie anti-homomorphism.

Now, my question.
I was reading about Hamiltonian actions of a Lie group $G$ over a manifold $M$ on *Representation Theory and Complex Geometry, by Chriss and Ginzburg, p. 42*, where you can read the following lines:

[image]

Are they assuming that $G$ acts on the right? Is there any convention in this field? Because before of this they made examples of natural (on the left) $G$-actions.

P.S. It doesn't seem to be a mistake because they use this fact in the next pages to define Hamiltonian actions for example. Unfortunately, I cannot find any pdf of the reference they give about this (would be great if anyone can tell me where to find it) which is *Orbits, Symplectic structure and Representation Theory, by Kostant, 1966*.

Comment: Exactly how do Chriss and Ginzburg define "the infinitesimal G-action"?

Comment: I did not find an explicit definition in their book

Comment: @JackLee they almost surely use the same convention as the one used in $\S 1.2$ of Meinrenken's notes (see link at the end of my answer below and in particular the proof of Theorem 1.6). From a representation theory point of view, it is the "natural" one to write down (at least if you have been trained to favour left actions/representations over right ones).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal C(X)$ the algebra of functions on $X$. (I'm being a bit vague here, because Lee's book works with smooth functions, but the Chriss-Ginzburg book sometimes works with algebraic varieties or complex manifolds in which case you would consider algebraic or analytic functions.) If $G$ acts on $X$ on the left, then there is a natural linear action of $G$ on $\mathcal C(X)$  given by
$$
g(f)(x) = f(g.x), \quad \forall g \in G, f \in \mathcal C(X), x \in X.
$$
However, a simple calculation shows that this gives a *right* action of $G$ on $\mathcal C(X)$, or if you prefer an anti-homomorphism from $G$ to $\text{Aut}(X)$ the group of (smooth) automorphisms of $X$.
If you differentiate this action you obtain the anti-homomorphism mentioned by the OP. One way to deal with this is simply to allow left and right linear actions as well as left and right group actions, but then one has to (repeatedly) specify which is intended.

Alternatively, one notes that groups and Lie algebras are equipped with a canonical anti-automorphism, so one can always switch between left and right actions using it. For groups this is the inversion map $\iota\colon G\to G$, given by $\iota(g)=g^{-1}$, while for Lie algebras, it is $a=d\iota(x)$ where $a(x) = -x$, for all $x \in \mathfrak g$. Thus, for example, if you take the induced action of $G$ on $\mathcal C(X)$ to be given by the formula $g(f)(x) = f(g^{-1}.x)$, then you obtain a left linear action (or left representation) of $G$ on $\mathcal C(X)$. If you then differentiate it you obtain a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak g \to \mathfrak X(X)$.

I expect that Chriss-Ginzburg simply failed to specify that they compose with the antiautomorphism $\iota$ or $a=d\iota$ in order to obtain a left-action. In general, it is a good idea to check the definition that is used when an action on a space is used to induce an action on functions on that space before doing any substantial calculations, because signs will change depending on the convention being used. (If the reference studies actions by nonabelian groups, it is likely that they will use the definition given in the formula above, but if all groups used in the reference are abelian (e.g. as may be the case when studying torus actions) then sometimes the definition $g(f)(x) = f(g(x))$.

A publicly available reference on this point can be found [here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/LectureNotes/action.pdf)
. Meinrenken uses the same choice of signs in \S1.2 of this note, and has a brief discussion on the issue in Remark 1.8.

Comment: So, if I got you, you are suggesting that they are taking the same definition of infinitesimal Lie algebra we can find in Lee's book apart from a sign. However, in other references (see Arnold for example) it's quite common to change the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{X}(X)$ to have a Lie homomorphisms.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean: when you say "infinitesimal Lie algebra" do you mean the Lie algebra of vector fields $\mathfrak X(X)$? The main point I was making, put more categorically, is that the functor from manifolds to algebras given by $X \mapsto \mathcal C^{\infty}(X)$ is contravariant, because if $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ is a smooth map, $\varphi^*(f) = f\circ \varphi \in \mathcal C^{\infty}(X)$ for all $f \in \mathcal C^{\infty}(Y)$. That means the opposite group $\text{Aut}(X)^{\text{op}}$ acts naturally on $\mathcal C^\infty(X)$ rather than $\text{Aut}(X)$ itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo, I meant "infinitesimal Lie algebra action"

Comment: In that case, yes, I am saying that Chriss-Ginzburg are using a convention that differs from Lee's book by a sign. I must confess that I'm not sure which work of Arnol'd you mean though! It seems strange to me to use a Lie bracket on vector fields which is not the commutator bracket.

Comment: I have two references in which you can find that choice of bracket on vector fields. They are: Kirillov - "Quiver Representations and Quiver Varieties" and Arnold - "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics" (the latter is used by Kirillov to justify his choice)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the reference. Arnol'd does indeed define the Lie bracket of vector fields to be the negative of the commutator, and of course that also works, because if you have an anti-homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathfrak g_1 \to \mathfrak g_2$, you can of course compose with the canonical anti-automorphism on $\mathfrak g_1$ or $\mathfrak g_2$ to obtain a homomorphism. Arnol'd claims his convention matches that used in the theory of Lie groups is not correct however -- it may be the convention in some literature on Lie groups, but it is not universal!

Comment: Yes, basically they say "we take the natural Lie algebra action and the unusual Lie bracket on vector fields". Instead others take "the unusual Lie algebra action and the natural Lie bracket on vector fields". Now you see my problems. However, I'm going to post an answer to explain what is the Chriss-Ginzburg convention and why. Thank you!